# How to read data from COM port using batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, serial-port, batch-file

Is there a DOS/ Batch command which can be used for reading from the COM port?

I tried to look for that but didn't find solution.

Comment: Remember to set the port parameters first (Baud rate, parity, data, stop and start bits and Retry). And beware that reading a COM port without control logic is very failure-prone.

Comment: For reading information from COM port I tried using type COM{n} command but it does not seems to be working. Do we have to set any particular configuration before using this command. Also what do I need to do to read data from COM port into some text file??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For reading some information from COM port you can try next command:

```
type COM{n}
```

For sending info to COM port use next command:

```
echo some text > COM{n}
```

Comment: @ethanpil: I have no chance to try, but  `set /p line=<com{n}` should work.

Comment: Does it work if the coming data from COM1 is binary data?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified". COM port exists. Writing to com port works if full path \\.\COM1 specified, but the question is about reading.